# How to set custom segue actions through navigation controllers for viewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I would like to have my application have custom buttons in the CameraViewController; one pushes to Rustles ViewController (Top VC in photo below) and the other transitions to ViewController (Bottom VC).

Right now my application can properly segue to the viewControllers by using the following method:

```
-(void)segueToRustlesTableViewController{
if (debug==1) {NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));} // simple debug statement, can ignore

// Instantiate nav controller which segues to table view
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil]; // must assume only IPhone
RustlesTableViewController *rustlesTVC = (RustlesTableViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RustlesView"];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tableSegue" sender:self];
[self.PickerController presentViewController:rustlesTVC animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

However when I get to the `UIViewControllers` I can't transition back to the old `UIViewControllers`, presumably because I have no Navigation Controllers embedded in each `UIViewControllers`.

My code right now wouldn't work for a NavigationController but I don't really know how to transition to the NavigationController and then the `UIViewControllers` after the Navigation Controller.

How do I transition from CameraViewController to a`NavigationController` and then to the RustlesViewController?

[image: Navigation Stack]

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't making use of a navigation controller, I would make a custom button in the spawned view controller (Rustles, View) and call
`[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

I believe this should work.